# Add text into a desktop application

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I would like to come up with a simple application that would add a specific phrase into a specific location on a desktop application.  I assume this isn't very hard, but I'm kind of new.  Any help??

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for an existing application or one that you are making yourself?

Comment: When you say "add a phrase to a specific location on a desktop applciation" do you mean the desktop application has a textbox or lable with some text and you want to add the phrase to that, or do you want to render the phrase on top of the application at a specific location?

Comment: I would like to insert a specific phrase into a specific textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would try it like the accexplorer or spy++ do this.

see [Create tree like (Spy++ or AccExplorer 2.0) using Active Accessibility](http://www.windows-tech.info/14/d582c0599a6617bf.php)

you can then set the value of a control though the IAccessible interface

Comment: I would like to insert a specific phrase into a specific textbox